# Single key contains Multiple values in Map in scala

Tags: html, scala

I am New to scala. I want to create map for all bellow data contains PINCODE as key and All other field as value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>PINCODE</th>
    <th>Locality</th> 
    <th>PO_TYPE</th>
    <th>TALUK</th>
    <th>DISTRICT</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500001</td>
    <td>Hyderabad G.P.O.</td>
    <td>Branch Post Office</td>
    <td>Hyderabad</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500001</td>
    <td>Gandhi Bhawan</td>
    <td>Branch Post Office</td>
    <td>Nampally</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500001</td>
    <td>Hindi Bhawan</td>
    <td>Branch Post Office</td>
    <td>Nampally</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500002</td>
    <td>Hyderabad Jubilee</td>
    <td>Branch Post Office</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>500002</td>
    <td>Moghalpura Branch</td>
    <td>Post Office</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
    <td>HYDERABAD</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

for example: (output is something like bellow)

(500001, (Hyderabad G.P.O.,Branch Post Office,Hyderabad,HYDERABAD),
         (Gandhi Bhawan,Branch Post Office,Nampally,HYDERABAD),
         (Hindi Bhawan,Branch Post Office,Nampally,HYDERABAD))

(500002 ,(Hyderabad Jubilee,Branch Post Office,HYDERABAD,HYDERABAD),
         (Moghalpura Branch,Post Office,HYDERABAD,HYDERABAD))

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not make it a `Map[String, List[String]` ?

Comment: I did it like this :
`var nodes = Map.empty[String , List[String]]
nodes.+= ("123" ->(List("abc","xyz","pqr","mno")))`

But while inserting next time `nodes` get overwrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wanting [MultiMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html), example:

```
  val mm = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Set[String]] with mutable.MultiMap[Int, String]
  mm.addBinding(500001, "a")
  mm.addBinding(500003, "b")
  mm.addBinding(500001, "c")
  val l = mm.getOrElse(500001, List())
  println(l)
```

For `List` value type, you can set the `MultiMap` value type is: `List[String]`, like:

```
  val mm = new mutable.HashMap[Int, mutable.Set[List[String]]] with mutable.MultiMap[Int, List[String]]
  mm.addBinding(500001, List("a", "b"))
  mm.addBinding(500003, List("b", "c"))
  mm.addBinding(500001, List("c", "D"))
  val l = mm.getOrElse(500001, Set())
  println(l)
```

Output:

```
  Set(List(e, f), List(a, b))
```

Comment: Similar to this but I want to bind List of element with index not a single String.
Something like this:
`mm.addBinding(500001, List("a","b"))
mm.addBinding(500003, List("b","c"))
mm.addBinding(500001, List("c","D"))`

Comment: @DarshanManek, I have updated my answer by setting value type is `List[String]`, hopefully it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually a `Map` is supposed to `uniquely map` a `key` to a `value`.

So, if you want to store multiple value (lets assume `String`s) on the same key, you can make it a `Map[String, List[String]]`.

```
val map: Map[String, List[String]] = Map(
  "1" -> List("val_1_1", "val_1_2", "val_1_3"),
  "2" -> List("val_2_1", "val_2_2")
)
```

But... as for your case it looks like you are trying have "values" which are not `String`s but look more like address descriptions.

In this case why not create a class for Address ?

```
case class Address(
  locality: String,
  poType: String,
  taluk: String,
  district: String
)

// Now you can have you map

val map: Map[String, List[Address]] = Map(
  "500001" -> List(Address("Hyderabad G.P.O.", "Branch Post Office", "Hyderabad", "HYDERABAD"))
)

// define a function that we will use to add addresses without over-writing

def updateMapByAddingAddressWithPincode(
  map: Map[String, List[String]],
  pincode: String,
  address: Address
) = {
  val existingAddressListForPincode = map.getOrElse(pincode, default = List.empty[Address])
  map + (pincode -> address :: existingAddressListForPincode)
}

// now lets say, you want to add another address with same pincode "500001"

val newAddress = Address("Gandhi Bhawan", "Branch Post Office", "Nampally", "HYDERABAD")

val updatedMap = updateMapByAddingAddressWithPincode(
  map,
  "500001",
  newAddress
)
```

Comment: This is correct but if again I am going to add any value for "500001" then It will overwrite first value.
I want all values to be come in front of "500001".

Comment: Yes... that is what that `updateMapByAddingAddressWithPincode`. It will return an updated map without overwriting. You use that updated map later.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can mix-in you `Map[String, Set[String]]` with the trait `MultiMap` described here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html

Sample:

```
// first import all necessary types from package `collection.mutable`
import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }

// to create a `MultiMap` the easiest way is to mixin it into a normal
// `Map` instance
val mm = new HashMap[Int, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Int, String]

// to add key-value pairs to a multimap it is important to use
// the method `addBinding` because standard methods like `+` will
// overwrite the complete key-value pair instead of adding the
// value to the existing key
mm.addBinding(1, "a")
mm.addBinding(2, "b")
mm.addBinding(1, "c")
```

Comment: Similar to this but I want to bind List of element with index not a single String.
Something like this:
`mm.addBinding(500001, List("a","b"))
mm.addBinding(500003, List("b","c"))
mm.addBinding(500001, List("c","D"))`